# TURN Server WebRTC Hardware / Network Requirements

Tags: sockets, udp, webrtc, turn

I am currently being challenged (mentally) with the idea of scaling out a TURN server(s) from a novelty to something that scales based on call volume.

Subsequently, I am trying to understand the requirements from a hardware, network, and application perspective and it's associated cost. I have some specific questions come to mind I would love the community's help with wrapping my brain around.

1) Are the ports reused for multiple destinations simultaneously? It seems to me conceptually if it's UDP and the source ip/port, destination ip/port is enough of 4-tuple for uniqueness, I could see it theoretically possible but I've never seen documentation around this.

2) What is the time (if any) before ports are reused. If the TURN server has allocated ports 1234 and 1235 for a given time, when one or both of those sockets close, how long will it be before the TURN server re-allocates those ports as a result of another request.

3) How should I think about the hardware requirements (specifically CPU and memory) of my TURN server(s) as a function of number of concurrent calls?